# check if value from table A exists in table B and append it to query

Tags: sql

Table `A` columns: `id`, `who`, `when`

Table `B` columns: `id`, `why`

Basically I need ALL records from table `A`, BUT I also need an extra value appended, which is either 1 or 0; whether `id` exist in table `B`. I would imagine pseudo-query something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table A ...
and also append value is_exist = (SELECT 1 FROM table B WHERE A.id = B.id)
```

How to achieve this? I use MySQL/SQLite

Comment: When you say append, do you just want to add an indicator column? So the result will always have the same record count as Table_A, but with an additional field?

Comment: @Error_2646 YESS

Answer (score 1):

The ubiquitous way to check if a row exists is to use `exists`

```
select *, 
  case when exists (
    select * from TableB b where b.Id = a.Id
  ) then 1 else 0 end as ExistsInB
from tableA a;
```

Edit
Some databases such as MySql allow you to evaluate expressions as a true boolean and therefore this is also valid:

```
select *, (exists (select * from b where b.Id = a.Id)) ExistsInB
from a;
```

Comment: would it be possible skip `case` thing entirely and expect `exists` return either 1 or 0?

Comment: @Baltazar I just noticed you mention mysql in your question (but not tagged?) See my edit above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `LEFT JOIN` to match the records between `TABLE_A` and `TABLE_B` without eliminating non-matched records. You can then use a `CASE EXPRESSION` to return a specific value if a match is found. See below:

```
SELECT a.id,
   a.who,
   a.when,
   CASE
       WHEN b.id IS NOT NULL THEN 1
       ELSE 0
   END AS is_exist
FROM table_a a
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_b b ON a.id = b.id
```

Comment: Careful here. This assumes id is going to be unique in table_b.